# adding select list to Editable grid Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am testing how `Knockout.js` works, but am looking for a way to fix my select, so that i can choose my array. Here's my code.

**Controller (where I get my array)**

```
ViewBag.FakturaProdukterId = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( new SelectList(db.FakturaProdukters, "Id", "Overskrift"));
```

**Script**

```
var GiftModel = function (gifts) {
        var self = this;
        self.gifts = ko.observableArray(gifts);

            var Test = @Html.Raw((ViewBag.FakturaProdukterId));

            console.log(Test);


        self.addGift = function () {
            self.gifts.push({
                //default seleceted array value
                Beskrivelse: "",
                Pris: ""
            });
        };

        self.removeGift = function (gift) {
            self.gifts.remove(gift);
        };


//where Id is the value of Array.
    var viewModel = new GiftModel([
                { Id: 0, Beskrivelse: "Tall Hat", Pris: "39.95" },
                { Id: 1, Beskrivelse: "Long Cloak", Pris: "120.00" }
            ]);
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

            // Activate jQuery Validation
            $("form").validate({ submitHandler: viewModel.save });</script>
```

**and last i have my Cshtml:**

```
`<select data-bind="
                                options: Test,
                                optionsText: Text,
                                value: Value,
                                optionsCaption: 'Choose...'">

                            </select>`
```

to sum up, I  want the array to be binded with the select. If possible i would like to use the Html.helper
Thanks in Advance

Edit:
After editing to fitting the answer given, i get this error

```
    Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return gifts }"
Message: Unable to process binding "options: function (){return gifts }"
Message: gifts is not defined
    at options (eval at parseBindingsString (knockout-3.4.2.js:68), <anonymous>:3:60)
    at update (knockout-3.4.2.js:94)
    at function.a.B.i (knockout-3.4.2.js:73)
    at Function.Uc (knockout-3.4.2.js:52)
    at Function.Vc (knockout-3.4.2.js:51)
```

Comment: Your binding says options: Test, so you are binding the options from the select with the FakturaProdukterId?
Also your binding will not work because Test is not a property of the viewModel. Change the var Test = to self.Test =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are not binding with the correct variables, second your var Test is not known to knockout.
JS:

```
var GiftModel = function(gifts) {
    var self = this;

    self.gifts = ko.observableArray(gifts);
    self.selectedGift = ko.observable(@Html.Raw((ViewBag.FakturaProdukterId)));

    self.addGift = function () {
        self.gifts.push({
            //default seleceted array value
            Beskrivelse: "",
            Pris: ""
        });
    };

    self.removeGift = function (gift) {
        self.gifts.remove(gift);
    };

    return self;
}
```

HTML:

```
<select data-bind="options: gifts,
                   value: selectedGift,
                   optionsCaption: 'Choose...',
                   optionsText: 'Beskrivelse',
                   optionsValue: 'Id'">
</select>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/go715rd1/6/

Comment: Thanks, makes sense but am still getting this Error:
See edits in Topic, Can't insert code here.

Comment: Forgot to add a return value in the ViewModel, need to: return self at the end. (fixed codesample)

Comment: yea, makes sense. Still getting the same error. want me to update topic to updated code? if that makes it easiere for you? Thanks for all the help so far

Comment: I've created a JSFiddle for you, where you can see the code works.
https://jsfiddle.net/go715rd1/

Comment: ahh, i think i may not have defined my issue correctly. I want to use the "Text" from the Selectlist "FakturaProdukterId" where Value == Id.

Comment: i think the reason it doesn't work for me right now is that i don't have it on page.onload()? only thing i can see from your fiddle except for that its 100% the same.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7fuyL2nx/ Can you locate my error? i will vote you as answered Thanks for all the help.

Comment: You have the select in the foreach, I edited to what I think you are trying to accomplish? https://jsfiddle.net/7fuyL2nx/3/

Comment: Thanks man, works perfectly now :) i will try to style it a bit and test around some more. Thanks again for all your help.